# How can I make sure my power line network is secure?

Tags: networking, powerline-networking

I installed four powerline adapters in my apartment in a huge apartment building. I noticed that in the appartment two stories above me, the power line adapter is still able to connect to the other ones!

Is there a way to set up a password or other kind of security so that I don't share my internet with other 44 apartment units?

Normally the signal should stop at the power meter, do I have the right to force my electricity company to fix it?

Comment: Netgear POWERLINE AV+ 500 ADAPTER KIT-XAVB5501

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most of these plugs provide a security mechanism of some form. Did they come with a driver CD or something? i use Solwise EOP sockets, which support encryption but must be configured using a windows application.

Comment: Some powerline adapters have [security buttons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HomePlug#Security) you need to press when first installing them.

Comment: I think my adapter offers a one button security, how would i test that it works? I added the model to my question.

Comment: I know this is 2 years later, but for future reference, you can test if it works by doing a packet capture via a powerline adapter that isn't configured with encryption.

Answer (score 3):

You and your neighbors might be using the same make and model powerline adapter, and you are using the default security setting in it. You should change the default security settings. You did not specify OS or make & model of powerline.

EDIT: Removed info about changing Network Group Name and IP

Comment: Changing your workgroup or subnet does not offer any security. The traffic still travels over the line, and can be sniffed and recorded by any device with access to the data on the line.

Comment: Thanks Darth, I wasn't sure. Another reason why I will never use a powerline product.